# How to close a JFrame from a subclass in a different method?

Tags: java, swing

I have a button in my GUI that is supposed to close its window. However, its event handler is located in an `AbstractAction` subclass that is located in a seperate method from the `JFrame`. Because of this I cannot see a way to tell the `JFrame` to close from my `AbstractAction`.

Heres the basic layout of my code:

```
public PointWindow()
  {
    initialize();
  }

  public void initialize()
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    // JFrame stuff
    frame.setContentPane(createGUI());
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public JPanel createGUI()
  {
    JPanel gui = new JPanel();

    // Code....

    class MakeGraphACT extends AbstractAction 
    {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        frame.setVisible(false);  // <--- How to get this to work?
        frame.dispose();          // <---
        new GraphWindow(pointList);
      }
    }

    //Code...

    return gui;
  }
```

Have I done a bad job planning my code or am I just missing something obvious?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to throw a bunch of windows at the user? Can you name many applications that do this in real life? Answer: not many because it's not a pleasing user interface to work with. Perhaps you'd rather swap views with a CardLayout instead.

Comment: This is a really simple program that consists of two windows. I understand what you're saying, but I don't think its necessary for such a small application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the frame as a `final` parameter to the `createGUI()` method.
You will then be able to access it from within the inner class.

Comment: Why did I not think of that..? Alright, thanks for the fast reply!